# Rearrange rows i R – but only for a part of the columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to rearrange a data frame of mine a bit in R. I have a data frame (called `df`) like the one below, and want to move all the values in column `val_1` and `val_2` from row 4 and below, one row down.

```
  hour  day  val_1  val_2
1    0   31   18.3    3.2
2    1   31   16.5    3.6
3    2   31   15.7    2.7
4    3   31   16.7    2.9
5    4   31   18.0    2.1
6    5   31   18.1    1.9
```

The gap at row 4 in column `val_1` and `val_2` should be filled with `NA`, and the missing value in the new row 7 under `hour` and `day`should have the value `6` (increased by 1, compared to the value above) and `31` like shown here.

```
  hour  day  val_1  val_2
1    0   31   18.3    3.2
2    1   31   16.5    3.6
3    2   31   15.7    2.7
4    3   31     NA     NA
5    4   31   16.7    2.9
6    5   31   18.0    2.1
7    6   31   18.1    1.9
```

Hope you can help me out, so I can automate my little task here.

### UPDATE AND SOLUTION:

Thanks to Nico I worked out a solution to my problem. My solution is a bit different form the suggested, since this one moves down both `val_1`and `val_2`at the same time, instead of one at a time. The code looks like this:

```
# Get row number where the new row should be placed after
row.no <- nrow(subset(df, hour <= 2))

# Create a NA row with matching column names (column val_1 and val_2 in this case)
new.row <- df[1, 3:ncol(df)]
new.row[] <- NA

# Create new value, hour and day section
values <- rbind(df[1:row.no, 3:ncol(df)],
             new.row,
             df[-1:-row.no, 3:ncol(df)]
             )
hour <- c(df$hour, df$hour[nrow(df)]+1)
day <- c(df$day, df$day[nrow(df)])

# Combine everthing again
df.new <- cbind(hour, day, values)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's handle `val_1` and `val_2`

```
# Note the use of negative indices to "deselect" values
val_1 <- c(df$val_1[1:3], NA, df$val_1[-1:-3])
val_2 <- c(df$val_2[1:3], NA, df$val_2[-1:-3])
```

Now, let's add the new `hour` and `day`

```
hour <- c(df$hour, df$hour[length(df$hour)]+1)
# Unclear from the question where the value for day should 
# be taken from. I am assuming the last one 
day <- c(df$day, df$day[length(df$hour)])
```

And put everything back together

```
new.df <- data.frame(hour, day, val_1, val_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative is to combine `expand.grid` and `merge`, something like the following:

First, increment all the values of "hour" after row 3 by 1.

```
mydf$hour[-c(1:3)] <- mydf$hour[-c(1:3)]+1
```

Second, since our "hour" column now has a gap, we'll need to fill it in. We can do that with `seq`. We'll also use `expand.grid` to create all combinations of the values in "hour" and "day", giving us something to `merge` with.

```
merge(mydf, expand.grid(hour = seq(0, max(mydf$hour)), 
                        day = unique(mydf$day)), all = TRUE)
#   hour day val_1 val_2
# 1    0  31  18.3   3.2
# 2    1  31  16.5   3.6
# 3    2  31  15.7   2.7
# 4    3  31    NA    NA
# 5    4  31  16.7   2.9
# 6    5  31  18.0   2.1
# 7    6  31  18.1   1.9
```

Comment: Interesting method, but a few days after writing that I would be staring at it saying: "what the hell was I trying to do here?"

Comment: @nico, really? I thought `expand.grid` + `merge` was a fairly common approach to filling in missing rows in a `data.frame`, which is essentially what we're doing here, except by artificially adjusting the "hour" column.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: to be honest I never used it that way. I am not saying it is inherently bad, just that it is not the primary use of `expand.grid`. Adding a comment on top of that line would solve the issue of course.

Answer (score 0):

If `dat` is the dataset

```
 datNew <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(,ncol=4, nrow=nrow(dat)+1)),colnames(dat))
 datNew[dat$hour!=3,-(1:2)] <- dat[,-(1:2)]
 datNew[,1] <- (1:nrow(datNew))-1
 datNew[,2] <- dat[1,2]

  datNew
```

#### or

```
 dat1 <-  dat[c(1:3,NA,4:nrow(dat)),]
 dat1[4:nrow(dat1),1:2] <- rbind(dat1[5:nrow(dat1),1:2], dat1[nrow(dat1),1:2]+c(1,0))
 row.names(dat1) <- 1:nrow(dat1)
```